# Bash Error On Launch

Tags: bash

I start up my terminal and Bash runs automatically.

When it does I get this error:

```
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 1: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
-bash: /Users/user/.bash_profile: line 3: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Can you include the relevant section from `/Users/user/.bash_profile`?

Comment: Just rename `.bash_profile` to `asdfddsa` and it'll work :) Seriously. But then you may lose some BASH settings.

Answer (score 5):

There is an error in `/Users/user/.bash_profile` involving mismatched quotation marks. Look for mismatched quotes in the first line of that file.

Comment: +I. Note that Bash runs `.bash_profile` automatically, which is why you see this when you log in.